# How to inspect APK contents during runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Is there any way to view the contents of an APK during runtime? As in, how do I view a memory snapshot of a running APK, preferably in an emulator, and save those assets locally?

There is a game Idle Heroes which has game files encrypted (images, scripts, etc). I have had little luck decrypting the files. I'm assuming if I can view memory contents of the game, I can view these game assets in their raw form.

Is this something that is at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the apk has been build not in debug mode ( if it is in the store it is mandatory to build it in release mode) it is not possible to attach android studio to the application.

If it has been proguarded all the names of the file inside the apk has been obfuscated, but you could get the resources using some tool like apk to jar.

I really hope you aren't going to use this tools for some malicious intent.

Android is Open Source and the environment is open source, but as Android Developer I really hope that there is still an ethic between developers.

Comment: I'm interested in the games images for an informational discord bot. Nothing malicious. Since I only want the images, there should be a way, proguarded or not, to extract that data from memory during runtime, correct?

Comment: If you are interested in resources (assets in Android) you need to use tool like  http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk inside you will find all images 

If you want to see logs of apk you cant if it has been build with debuggable flag to false

Comment: The problem is that the images are encrypted, and the game decrypts them during runtime.

Comment: @CHollasch Note that assets like these images are very likely copyrighted, meaning you're not allowed to use them for your discord bot without permission

Answer (score 0):

You can use APK analyser from android studio build menu

Android studio---> Build --> Analyze apk

Comment: This will not inspect the games elements in runtime, unless I am missing something about the APK analyzer.